# How to optimize execution plan for a simple join of three tables

Tags: postgresql, explain

I have a relatively simple table structure and query but get an execution plan that seems to be not ideal. Especially the execution time makes me wonder.
This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE t_c (
        c_id uuid DEFAULT (md5(((random())::text || (clock_timestamp())::text)))::uuid NOT NULL,
        cn character varying NOT NULL,
        cs character varying,
        cp character varying
);

CREATE TABLE t_t (
        t_id uuid DEFAULT (md5(((random())::text || (clock_timestamp())::text)))::uuid NOT NULL,
        tp character varying,
        tn character varying,
        ts bigint NOT NULL,
        tt character varying,
        tii character varying(256) NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE t_t_c (
        t_id uuid NOT NULL,
        c_id uuid NOT NULL,
        mc_id uuid NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY t_c ADD CONSTRAINT t_c_pkey PRIMARY KEY (c_id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY t_t ADD CONSTRAINT t_t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (t_id);

CREATE INDEX t_c_cn_idx ON t_c USING btree (cn);
CREATE INDEX t_t_tii_idx ON t_t USING btree (tii);

ALTER TABLE ONLY t_c ADD CONSTRAINT t_c_unique UNIQUE(cn, cs, cp);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_cid_tid ON t_t_c USING btree (c_id, t_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_tid_cid ON t_t_c USING btree (t_id, c_id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY t_t_c ADD CONSTRAINT t_t_c_cid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES t_c(c_id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY t_t_c ADD CONSTRAINT t_t_c_mcid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (mc_id) REFERENCES t_c(c_id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY t_t_c ADD CONSTRAINT t_t_c_tid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES t_t(t_id);
```

t_c and t_t both have about 2 million rows, t_t_c has about 2 billion rows.

This is the query I want to run:

```
explain analyze select t_t.tii from t_t_c ttc join t_t tt on tt.t_id=ttc.t_id
JOIN t_c c on c.c_id=ttc.c_id
where c.cn = 'xxx'
group by t_t.tii
```

This results in:

```
Group  (cost=5118006.20..5119624.81 rows=718 width=8) (actual time=231430.737..233032.234 rows=712 loops=1)
  Group Key: t.tii
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5118006.20..5119621.22 rows=1436 width=8) (actual time=231430.730..233497.475 rows=937 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Group  (cost=5117006.18..5118455.45 rows=718 width=8) (actual time=231244.223..232715.561 rows=312 loops=3)
              Group Key: t.tii
              ->  Sort  (cost=5117006.18..5117730.81 rows=289854 width=8) (actual time=231244.213..231965.197 rows=295104 loops=3)
                    Sort Key: t.tii
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25821kB
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27140kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25404kB
                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=212629.56..5090709.22 rows=289854 width=8) (actual time=3618.432..229889.447 rows=295104 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: (ttc.t_id = tt.t_id)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..4877319.49 rows=289854 width=16) (actual time=1.869..224573.547 rows=295104 loops=3)
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_c c  (cost=0.00..54571.92 rows=408 width=16) (actual time=0.443..220.151 rows=310 loops=3)
                                      Filter: ((cn)::text = 'xxx'::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 652230
                                ->  Index Only Scan using idx_cid_tid on t_t_c ttc  (cost=0.70..11740.18 rows=8028 width=32) (actual time=0.884..719.911 rows=952 loops=930)
                                      Index Cond: (c_id = c.c_id)
                                      Heap Fetches: 885317
                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=201875.05..201875.05 rows=860305 width=24) (actual time=3599.908..3599.911 rows=692137 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 2097152  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 130208kB
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_t t  (cost=0.00..201875.05 rows=860305 width=24) (actual time=0.057..1950.674 rows=692137 loops=3)
```

Overall execution time was about 4 minutes. Especially the **hash join** and the **nested loop** take a long time.
Is there something to optimize, maybe adding another index?
I am also not sure that uuid is the best data type for t_id, c_id which are the primary/foreign keys. Maybe an integer datatype can improve performance?

Postgres version is 11.6

Thank you very much

Christian

Edit:
The modified query which uses EXISTS() results in a different execution plan but the execution time is nearly the same, maybe 10% better:

```
Gather  (cost=5043832.59..5251301.23 rows=30951 width=8) (actual time=210773.943..217715.805 rows=853778 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Hash Semi Join  (cost=5042832.59..5247206.13 rows=12896 width=8) (actual time=210762.956..217221.553 rows=284593 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (tt.t_id = ttc.t_id)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_t tt  (cost=0.00..201875.05 rows=860305 width=24) (actual time=0.393..4337.062 rows=698756 loops=3)
        ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=5039175.26..5039175.26 rows=292587 width=16) (actual time=210754.705..210754.707 rows=297660 loops=3)
              Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 50144kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..5039175.26 rows=292587 width=16) (actual time=1.127..209827.976 rows=297660 loops=3)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_c c  (cost=0.00..55789.33 rows=417 width=16) (actual time=0.961..394.992 rows=314 loops=3)
                          Filter: ((cn)::text = 'xxx'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 667056
                    ->  Index Only Scan using idx_cid_tid on t_t_c ttc  (cost=0.70..11869.46 rows=8111 width=32) (actual time=2.031..662.330 rows=947 loops=943)
                          Index Cond: (c_id = c.c_id)
                          Heap Fetches: 892980
Planning Time: 0.475 ms
Execution Time: 219290.828 ms
```

Comment: `t.tii` :: there is no table or alias `t` in your query. `FOREIGN KEY (mc_id)` :: there is no index with `mc_id` as its first  column.

Comment: Also: you are only selecting (disticnt) from **one** table `select t_t.ti ...` :: you can push the other two tables into an `EXISTS(...)` term.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, it is t_t.tii The foreign key mc_id referencing c_id in t_c is more to ensure consistency. Do you think that an index may help? m_c is not part of the query, so I don't think it has any impact here.

Comment: I don't care if it will help. For 1GB bridge tables, supporting indexes for FK's are mandatory from my point of view. (try to imagine how costly a delete on the other tables would be without it)

Comment: The `where c.cn = 'xxx'` appears to be non-selective (40%), causing a full table scan.  BTW: IIRC there have been problems with parallel workers (before Pg-12??)

Comment: A conditional index `ON t_c ( c_id) WHERE c.cn='xxx';` could probably help. (for this particular query)

Comment: Thats true, but the 'xxx' will be different every time the query is used, so this conditional index would only be helpful for this specific string.

Comment: The values  canot all be 40% selective. These text-fields all have low cardinalities?

Comment: Hmm, only 943 rows out of 2 million have the value 'xxx' in cn.
Which part of the execution plan gives the information, that the condition on c.cn is 40% selective? I don't see it.

Comment: Can you post EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM t_c WHERE cn='xxx' ? Just to clear things up.

Comment: Also what is the least selective value? SELECT cn, count( * ) FROM t_c GROUP BY cn ORDER BY count( * ) DESC LIMIT 5 -- Maybe the stats on column cn haven't been updated, and postgres doesn't think it is selective. If the EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the simple select above gives bogus row estimate, maybe analyze the table again or tune the stats a bit?

Comment: `Filter: ((cn)::text = 'xxx'::text) Rows Removed by Filter: 667056` (I assumed your table had 1M rows).  [BTW: COLLATION ?]

Comment: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM t_c WHERE cn='xxx'
returns:
    `Bitmap Heap Scan on t_c c  (cost=18.68..1443.06 rows=1000 width=145) (actual time=0.341..3.749 rows=943 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((cn)::text = 'xxx'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=938
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_c_cn_idx  (cost=0.00..18.43 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.201..0.203 rows=943 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((cn)::text = 'xxx'::text)
Planning Time: 3.069 ms
Execution Time: 5.447 ms`

=> It uses the index on cn, which is not used in the complex query. This is interesting.

Comment: xxx is not the most common string in the column.
The name "time" is the most selective value:
time      34803

lat      1075

lon      1035

altitude    995

temperature            982

I will try to update the stats on column cn.

Comment: Try to get rid of the parallel workers. `SET parallel_tuple_cost = 1111;` <<-- I don't know the exact flag name/values for this. [BTW: EAV model ?]

Comment: The reason the query doesn't use the index for cn='xxx' is that doing the sequential scan on that table (which is quite fast) makes it easier to parallelize the very slow index only scan loop.

Comment: `... rows=1000 width=145) (actual ...` The **1000** value is suspect; it is plugged-in if no valid estimate is present. (it could be a coincidence, though)

Answer (score 2):

> Heap Fetches: 885317

That is probably where pretty much all of your time goes.  Vacuum t_t_c so that the index only scan is effective.

And if that doesn't work, then turn on track_io_timing and show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query.

Comment: I will try the vacuum and see if that helps

Comment: The cycle-eater is not the seqscan, but the loop around it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid JOINing tables in your main query if you dont select any columns from them. Instead, push them down into an `EXISTS(correlated subquery)`

Simple rewrite, avoiding the (silly) `GROUP BY`:

---

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE 

SELECT /* distinct ? */ tt.tii
FROM t_t tt
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM t_t_c ttc
        JOIN t_c c on c.c_id = ttc.c_id
        WHERE c.cn = 'xxx'
        AND tt.t_id = ttc.t_id
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reordering the tables would help, although I doubt it. It would make the query more readable.

```
select t_t.tii from 
t_c c
JOIN t_t_c ttc USING (c_id)
JOIN t_t tt USING (t_id)
where c.cn = 'xxx'
group by t_t.tii
```

From the tests you did, cn is a pretty selective column, and "SELECT * FROM t_c WHERE cn=..." is fast. It's really weird postgres does the join in the wrong order. So, you could force postgres to begin with this and join with the other tables later:

```
WITH cids AS MATERIALIZED( SELECT c_id FROM c WHERE cn=... )
SELECT DISTINCT t_t.tii from 
cids
JOIN t_t_c ttc USING (c_id)
JOIN t_t tt USING (t_id)
```

Note I asked you the maximum number of rows for the most common value of cn to avoid the possibility of this MATERIALIZED CTE being huge. But 30k rows is fine.

You could also do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_t.tii from t_t
WHERE t_id IN (SELECT t_id FROM t_t_c WHERE c_id IN (
    SELECT c_id FROM t_c WHERE cn=...
))
```

If several c_ids have the same c_id in t_t_c this could be faster because IN()  removes duplicates. If this is not the case, then removing duplicates will be a waste of time, so it'll probably be slower. I'm interested in the results.

If the above queries insist on not using the multicolumn indices on your link table t_t_c, which they should definitely be using, then this should give a clue about why the original query has such a bad plan, and the question becomes, why is it not using the indices? Maybe a collation problem, or a type problem, something. Try to join just between t_c and t_t_c to see what happens. As I said above it's quite weird that it joins the tables in the wrong order, so there's probably a problem somewhere that isn't obvious at the moment, but manifests as an index that can't be used when it should be.

Comment: Reordering the joins had no impact, as expected.
I tried the version with nested subqueries and also only the one with a join between t_c and t_t_c only. Both are also very slow.
I think that jjanes comment about the high number of heap fetches causing the problem is right. I will do the vacuum and see if this helps.